# Battery power in the home: Fire Safety

Tags: batteries, safety, fuses

I would like to use 12v LED tape powered by an 8 x AA battery holder and switched with a motion sensor. This will be connected in my home 24/7, so I would like to know what precautions  (if any) I should take to protect from fires.

Perhaps I just need to fit an in-line blade fuse holder to the +ve wire from the battery holder? If so, what is the safest way to wire this in without introducing more risks? Or perhaps there is a simpler way, e.g. a battery holder with inbuilt fuse? But I cannot find any. Basically, I want to minimise complexity to fool-proof the solution (as I am very inexperienced!).

**Please note:** I have considered rechargeable 12v battery packs, but I can only find generic made-in-China types, which have bad reviews and don't sound particularly safe, so I think I should rule those out. However, a rechargeable solution would be ideal, if anyone has any suggestions! 10 x AA rechargeables would be difficult as I can't find a 10 bay charger (in the UK). (LED strip states 6 amps max, but I only expect 1 amp due to dimming, shortening, single colour, and other people's findings).

Answer (score 2):

You will almost certainly want rechargeable batteries for this, but AA cells will only give you 2-3 hours use from fully charged (usual capacity is 1.5-2.7Ah).

12V rechargeable battery packs are readily available for emergency lighting etc, so that part shouldn't be hard to deal with.

For safety, you should choose protection which will break the circuit before any components (LED tape, wires etc) melt or get so hot that something next to them burns.  If you are sure your normal current will never exceed 1A, then you might choose a 1.5A fuse, and ensure your wires are big enough to carry 5-6A without overheating.